# PHP MySQL Half-day room reservation

Tags: php, mysql, process

I'm currently building a web application to book a meeting room. There is no problem on building daily based booking. Now I would like to book a meeting room for half day.

This means I cannot use the datepicker like hotel booking system (the datepicker shows available date and grey out unavailable ones).

I really appreciate if anyone can give me some ideas on how to check the availability of the meeting room. Let's say a person reserved it for morning session. So others can reserve the evening session.

Do you have any idea on the process flow? Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest breaking down your problem into manageable chunks.
Perhaps you could break down a day into time-slots.

Morning (08:00-12:00) / Afternoon (12:00-16:00) / Evening (16:00 - 20:00) perhaps.

A user picks a date, then a timeslot free (if available).

You could further expand on this by finding which dates have got free timeslots (or non-free) and make the dates available/unavailable accordingly when playing out the date picker.

An alternative option might be to use a datetime picker: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Naturally, this would be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTimePicker` wherein along with date store reservation time too.

By default keep time as 24 hours so it works normally in your usual case scenario.

When selected specified time slot, store it in the system and show half day availability based on it.

Hope this helps!